# s3cmd put files from tar stdin: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: amazon-s3, pipe, stdin, tar, s3cmd

I was trying to upload files from stdin by s3cmd, by this command below

`tar cfz - folder | s3cmd put - s3://backups/abcd2.tar`

but sometimes I get ERROR

```
ERROR: Cannot retrieve any response status before encountering an EPIPE or ECONNRESET exception
WARNING: Upload failed: /abcd2.tar?partNumber=21&uploadId=... ([Errno 32] Broken pipe)
WARNING: Waiting 3 sec...
```

I think s3cmd is waiting to long for TAR and Amazon S3 close connection ([RequestTimeout](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-socket-connection-timeout-error/)).

How to solve this problem? Maybe add buffer between tar and s3cmd but how?